# Cordova build iOS release on the CLI failing codesign check

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcodebuild, ipa

I am trying to generate a release .ipa file from a Cordova built .app file for iOS using the xcodebuild tools.

I am on OSX v10.9.5, Xcode 6.0.1, Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7.

When I change directory to my Cordova project I run the following command:

```
cordova build ios --release
```

This generates the .app file in `platforms/ios/build/emulators` folder as expected.

I then run the following command to sign the .app:

```
codesign -s "code sign certificate" path-to/my.app
```

Which i then verify with:

```
codesign -dv path-to/my.app
```

This returns something like this to show that the .app is signed:

```
Identifier=com.myapp.name
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (i386)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=3942 flags=0x0(none) hashes=190+3 location=embedded
Signature size=4359
Signed Time=3 Oct, 2014 10:55:16 am
Info.plist entries=21
TeamIdentifier=TQY89NPL4X
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=2 size=1004
```

Which seems correct.

I then generate an archive from which to create an .ipa file:

```
xcodebuild clean archive -scheme myApp -target myApp -sdk iphoneos -configuration AdHoc CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="the code sign identity" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="UDID of provisioning profile"
```

This works fine and succeeds.

Using the generated archive I use this command to try to generate an .ipa file:

```
xcodebuild -project myApp.xcodeproj -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath /path-to/myApp.xcarchive  -exportPath $(pwd)/myApp.ipa CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="code sign identity" -alltargets -configuration Release
```

This does generate the .ipa in the correct place but I get a worrying notification/error that the codesign verification has failed:

```
Codesign check fails : /myApp.app: resource envelope is obsolete
```

I am concerned that the .ipa that is generated will be rejected by the app store upon submission due to the codesign failure.

Is there anything that I am doing incorrectly in the process?

How do I make the .app pass the codesign verification step?

Does it actually matter to pass codesign verification?

Is there a way to test the `.ipa` file prior to submission to guarantee that it will not be rejected?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the xcrun command to package the app and generate an ipa
[xcrun manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/xcrun.1.html)

Sample:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PRODUCTDIR}/${TARGET}.app" -o "${OUTDIR}/${TARGET}.ipa" --sign "${IDENTITY}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}"
```

I use this for creating .ipa 's that I can upload to TestFlight.

Comment: when i try this i get an error that says unable to copy the provisioning profile from it's existing location to a tmp folder

Comment: For the provisioning profile variable, are you passing it an absolute path or just the file name?

Comment: should i be using the absolute path or filename?

Comment: So I am using absolute path for my Provisioning profile and just a name for my code signing identity.

I would try running as su/sudo there could also be an issue with permissions if the error says unable to copy.

Comment: Just wanted to comment here, that testflightapp.com has officially gone down since the service was consumed by iTunes Connect.